# CSS, why does one thing work and not another?

Tags: css

Why does this work:

```
 <div style="background-color: #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;">testing 10,9,8,7
</div>
```

And this does not?

```
<div style="roundedCornerBox">
    testing 10,9,8,7
</div>
```

Where I have created a css file that says:

```
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}

roundedCornerBox {
   background-color: #ccc;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/style.css" />      
</head>

<body>
<div style="roundedCornerBox">
    testing 10,9,8,7
</div>

<div style="background-color: #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;">
        testing 10,9,8,7
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure you dont mean:

```
<div class="roundedCornerBox">
    testing 10,9,8,7
</div>
```

and

```
.roundedCornerBox {
   background-color: #ccc;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

You need the dot to identify a css class and to use that css class you need to place the class name in the class attribute on the dom element.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html#adef-style 
Definition of the style attribute.
Less technical and for once more useful w3schools breakdown of the difference: http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 3):

Classes start with a dot!

```
.roundedCornerBox {
   background-color: #ccc;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   padding: 10px;
}

<div class="roundedCornerBox">
```

Without the dot, it's looking for a `<roundedCornerBox />` element to style.  The `style=` needs to be `class=` as well.

Comment: Still won't work. Check his code carefully. He's putting the class name in the style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You want `class="roundedCornerBox"` in the markup and `.roundedCornerBox` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The `div` tag is incorrect in your second example. It could be

```
<div id="roundedCornerBox">
    testing 10,9,8,7
</div>
```

and

```
#roundedCornerBox {
   background-color: #ccc;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: That is if `roundedCornerBox` is a `class`. Another syntactically correct option is to make it an `id`. (*Semantically*, perhaps it is better as a `class`. Either way.)